# how do i use vuex mutation payload object properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have 2 inputs in which i provide value to search whether its name of the company, position (1st input) or location (2nd input). It works with one argument provided into foundJobs mutation and then into action. But when payload has an object everything is undefined and array is empty. What am i doing wrong?

component:

```js
<script setup>
import IconSearch from "../Icons/icon-search.vue";
import IconLocation from "../Icons/icon-location.vue";
import { ref } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

const store = useStore();

const nameFilter = ref("");
const locationFilter = ref("");
</script>

<template>
  <div class="header-filter">
    <div class="header-filter__search">
      <IconSearch />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Filter by title, companies, expertise…"
        ref="nameFilter"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="header-filter__location">
      <IconLocation />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Filter by location…"
        ref="locationFilter"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="header-filter__fulltime">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <p>Full Time Only</p>
      <button
        type="button"
        @click="
          store.dispatch('foundJobs', {
            nameFilter: nameFilter.value,
            locationFilter: locationFilter.value,
          })
        "
      >
        Search
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

vuex: (not working)

```js
import { createStore } from "vuex";

const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      jobs: [],
      filteredJobs: [],
    };
  },

  mutations: {
    setJobs(state, jobs) {
      state.jobs = jobs;
    },

    foundJobs(state, { nameInputValue, locationInputValue }) {
      let copiedJobsArr = [...state.jobs];

      if (nameInputValue !== "") {
        copiedJobsArr = copiedJobsArr.filter(
          (job) =>
            job.company === nameInputValue || job.position === nameInputValue
        );
      }
      if (locationInputValue !== "") {
        copiedJobsArr = copiedJobsArr.filter(
          (job) => job.location === locationInputValue
        );
      }

      console.log(locationInputValue); // undefined

      state.filteredJobs = copiedJobsArr;
      console.log(state.filteredJobs); //empty array
    },


   
  },

  actions: {
   
    foundJobs(context, { nameInputValue, locationInputValue }) {
      context.commit("foundJobs", { nameInputValue, locationInputValue });
    },

    loadJobs(context) {
      return fetch("./data.json")
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          const transformedData = data.map((job) => {
            return {
              id: job.id,
              company: job.company,
              logo: job.logo,
              logoBackground: job.logoBackground,
              position: job.position,
              postedAt: job.postedAt,
              contract: job.contract,
              location: job.location,
              website: job.website,
              apply: job.apply,
              description: job.description,
              reqContent: job.requirements.content,
              reqItems: job.requirements.items,
              roleContent: job.role.content,
              roleItems: job.role.items,
            };
          });
          context.commit("setJobs", transformedData);
        });
    },

   
  },

  getters: {
    jobs(state) {
      return state.jobs;
    },


    filteredJobOffers(state) {
      return state.filteredJobs;
    },
  },
});


export default store;
```

vuex (working) - here i also provide one argument into action assigned to a button (in a component file)

```js
import { createStore } from "vuex";

const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      jobs: [],
      filteredJobs: [],
    };
  },

  mutations: {
    setJobs(state, jobs) {
      state.jobs = jobs;
    },


    foundJobs(state, nameInputValue) {
      let copiedJobsArr = [...state.jobs];

      if (nameInputValue !== "") {
        copiedJobsArr = copiedJobsArr.filter(
          (job) =>
            job.company === nameInputValue || job.position === nameInputValue
        );
      }

      console.log(nameInputValue);

      state.filteredJobs = copiedJobsArr;
      console.log(state.filteredJobs);
    },

 
  },

  actions: {

    foundJobs(context, nameInputValue) {
          context.commit("foundJobs", nameInputValue);
        },




    loadJobs(context) {
      return fetch("./data.json")
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          const transformedData = data.map((job) => {
            return {
              id: job.id,
              company: job.company,
              logo: job.logo,
              logoBackground: job.logoBackground,
              position: job.position,
              postedAt: job.postedAt,
              contract: job.contract,
              location: job.location,
              website: job.website,
              apply: job.apply,
              description: job.description,
              reqContent: job.requirements.content,
              reqItems: job.requirements.items,
              roleContent: job.role.content,
              roleItems: job.role.items,
            };
          });
          context.commit("setJobs", transformedData);
        });
    },


   
  },

  getters: {
    jobs(state) {
      return state.jobs;
    },

    
    filteredJobOffers(state) {
      return state.filteredJobs;
    },
  },
});


export default store;
```

Comment: You gave payload properties odd names, nameInputValue and locationInputValue. You can't expect them to be filled by magic when you dispatch it like `{
            nameFilter: nameFilter.value,
            locationFilter: locationFilter.value,
          }` Also don't use strict `!== ""` comparison if you need a check that a value is falsy, it will make it work worse in unexpected cases like this one

Comment: Thanks, a lot, totally forgot that names have to be equal while dispatching - thought that only order matters.

Comment: The order would matter if payload were an array and not plain object, which is possible too but much less practical

Answer (score 0):

```
store.dispatch('foundJobs', {
    nameFilter: nameFilter.value,
    locationFilter: locationFilter.value,
})
```

You are sending data like this and trying to get on the wrong way

```
foundJobs(state, { nameInputValue, locationInputValue })
```

you can receive data this way:

```
foundJobs(state, { nameFilter, locationFilter})
```